# How to add vertices to existing linestrings?

Tags: postgis, point, linestring, merge

If I have

```
Linestring(1 2, 1 5, 1 9)
```

and a

```
Point(1 3)
```

Is there any function that can merge linestring and point preserving the order 
so output would be:

```
Linestring(1 2, 1 3, 1 5, 1 9)
```

Comment: So you'll just be adding vertices to existing lines?

Comment: yes, add vertice to existing linestring, resulting in a linestring.

Comment: Why do you need to do it btw?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the LineString is simply to be subdivided at a position closest to the given Point, you could do what you want with this (splits LineString at closest Point to given Point and remerges the two segements afterwards)

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
         ST_LineMerge(
           ST_Union(
             ST_Line_Substring(line, 0, ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, point)),
             ST_Line_Substring(line, ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, point), 1)
       )))
FROM  ST_GeomFromText('Linestring(1 2, 1 5, 1 9)') as line, 
      ST_GeomFromText('Point(1 3)') as point;
```

However, if your Point is not supposed to be projected on the LineString, this will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Do this using [`ST_Snap`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_Snap.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_Snap( 
  'Linestring(1 2, 1 5, 1 9)',
  'Point(1 3)',
  0.1
));
```

```
          st_astext          
-----------------------------
 LINESTRING(1 2,1 3,1 5,1 9)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, also for MultiPoints and MultiLinestrings.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I ended up using ST_Snap with ST_LineInterpolatePoints:
`ST_Snap(border, ST_LineInterpolatePoints(border, LEAST(20/ST_Length(border),1), true),0.001) border`. This way I can add regularly spaced new points on a line.

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS has [ST_AddPoint](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AddPoint.html) that should allow you to do this though you'd have to specify where to add the point.

> ST_AddPoint — Adds a point to a LineString before point 
>   (0-based index).

Examples:

```
--guarantee all linestrings in a table are closed
        --by adding the start point of each linestring to the end of the line string
        --only for those that are not closed
        UPDATE sometable
        SET the_geom = ST_AddPoint(the_geom, ST_StartPoint(the_geom))
        FROM sometable
        WHERE ST_IsClosed(the_geom) = false;

        --Adding point to a 2-d line
        SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_AddPoint(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(1 2, 1 5, 1 9)'), ST_MakePoint(1, 3), 1));

        --result
        st_asewkt
        ----------
        LINESTRING(1 2, 1 3, 1 5, 1 9)
```

Comment: yeah, i know for this function but i do not know where should i put my new point.