# Locate ways (multilinestring) that intersect points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, sql, linestring

I have two tables: crimes (points/ST_MakePoint) and ways (multilinestring). Initially what I did was reposition the points to the point closest to the track using the following:

```
UPDATE renzagoras.delitos as d 
SET   geom = ( 
    SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(r.geom, d.geom) 
    FROM   renzagoras.gis_osm_roads_free_1 r 
    WHERE  ST_DWithin(d.geom, r.geom, 10) 
    ORDER BY r.geom <-> d.geom LIMIT 1 ) 
WHERE _id = :id
```

Now I am interested in knowing which are the ways where these points are located and for this I tried to use ST_Intersect but it did not return all the ways (only some). Has anyone already experienced this type of case?

[image: points and ways]

Comment: It's extremely unlikely for points to intersect lines due to floating-point precision issues. Use a ST_DWithin with a small tolerance instead.

Comment: And if intersection is a must, then you can add vertices to the lines at the proper locations, see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40622/how-to-add-vertices-to-existing-linestrings) and its `st_snap` solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue with derived geometries and the capacity of the numerical data types used to calculate the intersection between a positional and a direction vector - i.e. floating point inaccuracies.

---

I'd suggest to include the way id in the `UPDATE` statement; assuming you have another column `way_id` in your `renzagoras.delitos` table, run:

```
UPDATE
  renzagoras.delitos as d 
  SET
    (way_id, geom) = (
      SELECT
        <id>,
        ST_ClosestPoint(r.geom, d.geom)
      FROM
        renzagoras.gis_osm_roads_free_1 r 
      ORDER BY
        r.geom <-> d.geom
      LIMIT 1
    )
;
```

Alternatively, you can run a *(K)NN* query to identify the way ids:

```
SELECT
  d.*,
  w.<id>
FROM
  renzagoras.delitos as d 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT
    <id>
  FROM
    renzagoras.gis_osm_roads_free_1 r 
  ORDER BY
    r.geom <-> d.geom
  LIMIT 1
) AS w
;
```

Comment: It really worked, thank you very much and I hope this answer will serve more people.